# C++ const semantics for a reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants, semantics

If there is something like below in code:

```
func(const base& obj)
```

what does the const semantics mean? What is constant here ? Is obj a `const reference to a non-const object` or a `non-const reference to a const object`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj` is a *reference to a `const` object*.

There is no such thing as a "non-const reference", since a reference cannot be changed to refer to something else after it has been created.

Comment: So only a const object can be passed as the argument of `func`?

Comment: Any object (either const or not) can be passed as the argument. However, within the function `func()`, use of the object is restricted to only those operations that are valid on a `const` object. So the caller knows that calling `func(obj)` will not change `obj`.

Comment: Thanks .That was so useful for a beginner like me :)

Comment: there is a const reference : can not modify object referenced. and reference to an object hat can change the content of the referenced object. so, there is

Comment: @Greg Hewgill : your answer is wrong : "non-const reference" exists according to the standard. your eplanation is wrong. "non-const reference" means a reference that is able to change the content of referenced object. it is on the standard. check it.

Comment: @eharvest: I'm using the word "reference" in the same way as one would use "pointer". There is a big difference between "const pointer" and "pointer to const".

Comment: this is true for pointer but not for references.   the behaviour and use of references is different from pointers.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That is why I choose to say "reference to const" instead of "const reference".

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as a "non-const" reference, that is, a reference is always bound to the same object and there is no way to change that.  "const type&" means reference to const type.

Comment: so `const base &obj` can also be used as `base const &obj`?

Comment: that is wrong. according to the standard, non-const references exist.

Comment: wrong too :  "const type&" means reference to const type.  according to the standard, this is const reference to whether const or non const object.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: "const base&" and "base const&" are the same type.

Comment: @eharvest: references to non-const objects exist.  References which are themselves mutable (i.e., can change which object they refer to) do not exist in C++.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a const reference. You have a ' referential access ' to data that's passed but you cannot modify it.

Answer (score 2):

Without const you will be not able to send a const object to that function. So it is always a positive  to add const. especially when you are creating function for many users. Classic examples are setters functions.

```
x->setXsth(sth& obj)              // works only with  non-const object. 
x->setXsth(const sth& obj)        //works with  const object and non-const.
```

Answer (score 1):

obj is a reference to const base, so it means you are not allowed to change referenced object. It can be written as

```
func(const base& obj)
```

or

```
func(base const & obj)
```

Use right-left rule for reading such declarations types, for this simple example just read it from the right. More on that here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/complex_declarations.aspx

Comment: also, even thought : 'base const & obj' might look strange at first, it is easier to read, you just go from right exactly as written: obj is a reference to const base

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is a constant reference to an object (wether the object is const or non const) passed in argument to `func()`

if you write : `func(B);`

this means that you cannot change the content of `B` inside the function `func()`

(where `func(const base& obj)`)

Comment: thx for comment, dunno... :) i wrote correct and helpfull answer

Comment: I didn't downvote, but whoever did probably objected to "const reference to object".  Most would say "reference to const object".

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth : i understand your answer. but this tyoe of references are usually called : constant reference.

Comment: But there's no such thing as a "non-const reference", so it's only necessary to say "reference".

Comment: no, there is contant reference and reference : the first can not change the  content of referenced object, the second can.

Comment: @eharvest: We call these "reference to T" and "reference to const T".

Comment: wrong in standard : you can not call is reference to "const T" !!!        (i eplain or you, T could be const or non const, but the reference could not change T content).

Comment: Const reference is written on standard.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Because "const reference" is known to impossible (or redundant), it's extremely common to say "const-reference to T" in place of "reference to const T". I do it every time.

Comment: i can not understand why people say think not logical and false and continue to do so even when i explain

Comment: @GMan, you are wrong, it is not reference to const T, it is const reference (whether T is const or non const ).

Comment: see the standard text ! it talks about const reference. const reference is diferent from reference to const T (althow this reference have to be eclared as const). see answer of @Michal

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unsolicited answer/viewpoint: The *const* modifier modifies whatever is on its left-hand-side, except for the one construction that you're using (in which case it modifies whatever is immediately to the right). I find it easier to always stick *const* immediately on the right of whatever I want to modify, and read the statement right-to-left. Maybe this isn't the best way to do things, but it helps me to keep it straight.

Examples:

```
// these two statements are equivalent
const int x = 5; // special case usage
int const x = 5;

// using the LHS syntax makes multiple consts easier to understand
int const y = 6;
int const * const x = &y; // x is a const pointer to const int

// const can apply to pointers but not to references
int const & const z = y; // redundant, references are always const
```

Answer (score -1):

As other answers have said, `obj` is a reference to a `const base` object. However, that doesn't mean the object it refers to either has exactly the `base` type, or that the object it refers to is `const`, just that `func` can't modify `obj` *through **that** reference*. For example:

```
struct derived : base { ... };
derived d;
func(d);
```

is legal, and:

```
bool other_func(const base& b, other_object& o) {
   base b_copy = b;
   o.foo();
   return b_copy == b;
}
```

may return `false` if `o` has an internal non-const reference to `b` (or something inside it) and `o.foo()` modifies `b`. This has practical implications for functions like

```
std::string::operator=(const std::string& other);
```

where a naive implementation might do the wrong thing for `my_str = my_str`.